# Java Concurrency with Atomic Class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, atomic, java-threads

As I know operations on Atomic classes of Java concurrency API are executed one after one when trying to execute the same operation from multiple threads, the output of the following program seems inconsistent to me.

```
public class VisitorCounterAtomic {

    private AtomicInteger visitorCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void visitAndPrint() {
        System.out.println("Total Visitors: " + visitorCount.incrementAndGet());
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ExecutorService service = null;
        VisitorCounterAtomic counter = new VisitorCounterAtomic();

        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                service.submit(() -> counter.visitAndPrint());
        } finally {
            if (null != service) service.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Total Visitors: 1
Total Visitors: 4
Total Visitors: 2
Total Visitors: 5
Total Visitors: 3
Total Visitors: 6
Total Visitors: 7
Total Visitors: 8
Total Visitors: 9
Total Visitors: 10
```

**My expected output:**

```
Total Visitors: 1
Total Visitors: 2
Total Visitors: 3
Total Visitors: 4
Total Visitors: 5
Total Visitors: 6
Total Visitors: 7
Total Visitors: 8
Total Visitors: 9
Total Visitors: 10
```

I know I could generate my expected output by using `synchronization` block, but I need an explanation why not using only atomic variable generate the expected output.

My reasoning is like - Regardless of the order of thread execution it will increment and print before another thread increments and prints the value of the atomic variable.

Comment: Calls to `visitorCount.incrementAndGet()` are executed in order.  Startup of threads, however, is not guaranteed to occur in any particular order.  When call a thread’s `start()` method, that Thread’s Runnable will be executed *some time later.*  Exactly when is operating system dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual order doesn't have any relation with `AtomicInteger`.
`AtomicInteger` guarantees that the value may be updated atomically. It doesn't guarantee that the threads are sequentially executed.
Indeed the `ExecutorService` instance processes the tasks in an asynchronous way.
So you cannot have a predictable task completion order.
Actually you have a race condition between the execution of `incrementAndGet()`and `println()`:

```
public void visitAndPrint() {        
    System.out.println("Total Visitors: " + visitorCount.incrementAndGet());
}
```

For example suppose :

- thread A executes `visitorCount.incrementAndGet()` (counter = 1) but not `println()`
- thread A is paused
- thread B executes `visitorCount.incrementAndGet()` (counter = 2) and `println()`
- Thread A is resumed. `println()` is executed

Result :

> Total Visitors: 2
>
> Total Visitors: 1

By synchronizing the method you should have the expected order :

```
public synchronized void visitAndPrint() {        
    System.out.println("Total Visitors: " + visitorCount.incrementAndGet());
}
```

Comment: I got you explanation although I considered this myself before I posted the question. I needed a clarification from someone else. So the main reason is thread **pause/resume** and atomic operation of **incrementAndGet()** doesn't prevent printing the value using **System.out.println** in an unordered way. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The **AtomicInteger** class provide the Atomic Operation. It means it will make sure that only one thread at a time do the operation on that variable. It is **Non blocking** in nature as well. Here in your code multiple threads are running at the same time so **AtomicInteger** is doing its Job Pretty well but which thread will complete its task first it is not depend on **AtomicInteger**.

To solve this problem, You can use Syncronized Function to solve this Problem.